# A loop to analyze a signal over intervals in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a known signal `x`, which I want to analyze after every 10s:

```
t = 1:1:100;           %time
x = 8*sin(t);          %the signal
a1= 5;                 %known coefficient for the first 10s
```

For this signal I perform the first analysis for the first 10s:

```
%analysis 1
x1 = x(1:11);
y1 = x1*a1;
y_mean1 = mean(y1);
a2=y_mean1;            %coefficient necessary for the next 10s
```

Now I perform the analysis for the next 10s:

```
%analysis 2
x2 = x(12:22);
y2 = x2*a2;
y_mean2 = mean(y2);
a3 = y_mean2;          %coefficient necessary for the next 10s
```

And this would be repeated for the total length of the signal. However, this approach is not the most convenient I imagine. How do I put in a loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `1:11` is actually 11 seconds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to loop:

```
n=10;
a = 5;
y_mean = [];
for ind = 1:n:100
    y = x(ind:ind+n)*a;
    a = mean(y);
    y_mean(end+1) = a;
end
```

But you can probably find a way to do it without loops `mean(reshape(x, 10, []))` is a good start and check out `cumsum` style functions etc to finish it off.

Comment: +1 I hadn't seen you already gave the `reshape`-based answer, so I wrote mine

Answer (score 2):

No need for a loop.

1. If the block size divides the length of `x`: [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) into a matrix and take the [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) of each column:

   ```
   n = 10; %// block size. Assumed to divide numel(x)
   a = mean(reshape(x, n, []));
   ```
2. In the general case, where the last block may be smaller: label each block with an integer value and apply [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) using those labels:

   ```
   a = accumarray(ceil((1:numel(x))/n).', x(:), [], @mean).';
   ```

   Or use [`vec2mat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html) (Communications Toolbox) to build a matrix with `NaN` as fill value for the last block, and then apply [`nanmean`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/nanmean.html) to compute means ignoring `NaN`:

   ```
   a = nanmean(vec2mat(x, n, NaN).', 1);
   ```

   Or do the filling directly:

   ```
   a = nanmean(reshape([x(:); NaN(mod(mod(-numel(x),n),n),1)], n, []));
   ```

Comment: `vec2mat` is in a toolbox, but it's pretty easy to replicate using `mod` and `reshape`, might be worth adding the alternative (even though the `accumarray` solution works in all situations

Comment: @Dan Good idea. Updated (I found a nice way using `mod` twice)